# putty psftp " and ; in password

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a vbscript to connect to a FTP server using putty.  The problem I am having is the password has a ; and " in it.  I have tried putting the password in " and also using \ to escape the charters

e.g.

-pw 3this;IsMyPwd" is what i want to use
Tried 
"3this;IsMyPwd""" -> putty does not connect to remote server
-pw 3this;IsMyPwd""" -> putty does not connect to remote server

3this\;IsMyPwd\" -> putty does not connect to remote server
3this;IsMyPwd\" -> putty does connect to remote server but asks for a password or just hangs

-pw 3this;IsMyPwd"" > putty does connect to remote server but asks for a password or just hangs

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to not use putty.  I used WinSCP.  You do not have to install it on the server you can copy WinSCP.com and WinSCP.exe to a folder.

Create a file with the commands, note that %22 url encoding of "
example of Cmd.txt file

```
# Automatically abort script on errors
option batch abort
# Disable overwrite confirmations that conflict with the previous
option confirm off
# Connect
open sftp://USERNAME:password%3%22@ftp.server.org
ls
cd to_folder
ls
close
exit
```

Run the command C:\winScp> winscp.com /script=Cmd.txt